# Lagrange Multiplier inconsistent

Tags: optimization, lagrange-multiplier

max $f(x,y,z)$
subject to $x+y+z=1$

$$f(x,y,z)= - (x+0.5y)\log(x+0.5y) -2(0.25y+0.5z)\log(0.25y+0.5z)-\log(2)(1.5y+z)$$

$$\frac{\partial F}{\partial x} = - (1+\log(x+0.5y))$$
$$\frac{\partial F}{\partial y} = -0.5(1+\log(x+0.5y)) - 0.5(1+\log(0.25y+0.5z) -1.5\log(2)$$
$$\frac{\partial F}{\partial z} = - (1+\log(0.25y+0.5z)-\log(2)$$

setting $$\frac{\partial F}{\partial x} = \lambda$$
$$\frac{\partial F}{\partial y} = \lambda$$ 
$$\frac{\partial F}{\partial z} = \lambda$$ 
$$x+y+z=1$$

and solving with $$\frac{\partial F}{\partial y} =\frac{\partial F}{\partial x} $$
we get $$x+0.5y=e^{3\log(2)}\left(0.25y+0.5z\right).$$

similarly solving with $$\frac{\partial F}{\partial x} =\frac{\partial F}{\partial z} $$
we get $$x+0.5y=e^{\log(2)}\left(0.25y+0.5z\right).$$

The two equations obtained by solving for $\lambda$ are inconsistent. Why ?

Comment: The function isn't well defined. For example in $(x,y,z)=(3,-1,-1)$ we have the subexpression $\log(-0.25-0.5)$.

Answer (score 2):

I think there exists no solution, which would also explain the inconsistency. I found this by transforming your problem to apropriate coordinates

$$X=x+\frac{y}{2} \\
Y=\frac{y}{4}+\frac{z}{2}\\
Z=\frac{3y}{2}+z$$

The side conditions then become $X+2Y=0$ resulting in the Lagrange function

$$L(X,Y,Z,\Lambda)=F(X,Y,Z)+\Lambda(X+2Y)$$

with 
$$F(X,Y,Z)=-X\log X -2Y\log Y -Z\log2.$$

Your equations are

$$0 =L_\Lambda=X+2Y\\
  0 =L_X=-\log X-1+\Lambda\\
  0 =L_Y=-2\log Y-2+2\Lambda\\
  0 =L_Z=-\log 2$$

where the last equation cannot be solved. If I didn't make a mistake there is no extremum.

Comment: Simple brute force over a range of values x=[0,1], y=[0,1], z=[0,1] yields F(x,y,z)=1 maximum where x=0.5, y=0, z=0.5. I am primarily interested in x,y,z in this range. So can I prove this with inequality constraints ?

Comment: If you have a **bounded** domain $D=[0,1]^3$ this is a different story. In this case if you don't find inner solutions, you might have solutions on the boundary. This is consistent with your numerics, as your point $(0.5,0,0.5)$ is on the boundary. These solutions can be found "by hand" as you did, you can also do this analytically, but it is much work. Your range $D$ is a unit cube, so your boundary has 6 sides, which you would have to analyze. On each side you would have an optimization problem on a 2D square with **two** side conditions, can you follow?

Comment: Yes I can follow. How can I do it analytically? And can you mention me a reference/book which talks about such cases appearing in solving Lagrange Multiplier questions ?

Comment: I don't know any book, but the basic idea is just very simple. It's like saying, that for $f(x)=x$ on the range $x\in D=[0,1]$, you cannot solve $f'(x)=0$, but there is an extremum at $x=1$. Here $D$ is 1D, so the boundary has zero dimension and discussing it is trivial: Just check two points $x=0,1$. If your domain $D$ is 2D, e.g. a square, $D=[0,1]^2$, your boundary is four line segments $\{0\}\times[0,1], \{1\}\times[0,1], [0,1]\times\{0\}, [0,1]\times\{1\}$...

Comment: ...On each line segment you get a new Lagrange problem, which is just your old problem plus another side condition, e.g. for the first segment the additional condition would be $x=0$. Try to discuss this for 3D now ;)

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that we are working with natural logarithms (this is not essential to the outcome -- and I won't ask where you acquired such a *lovely* function).  I agree with your partial derivatives, so we have the results

$$\frac{\partial F}{\partial x} \  = \ \frac{\partial F}{\partial y} \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ x \ + \ \frac{1}{2}y \ = \ 8 \ \left(\frac{1}{4}y \ + \ \frac{1}{2}z\right) \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ x \ - \ \frac{3}{2} y \ - \ 4z \ = \ 0 \ \ , $$

$$\frac{\partial F}{\partial x} \  = \ \frac{\partial F}{\partial z} \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ x \ + \ \frac{1}{2}y \ = \ 2 \ \left(\frac{1}{4}y \ + \ \frac{1}{2}z\right) \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ x \ - \ z \ = \ 0 \ \ , $$

$$\frac{\partial F}{\partial y} \  = \ \frac{\partial F}{\partial z} \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ 2 \ \left(x \ + \ \frac{1}{2}y\right) \ = \ \frac{1}{4}y \ + \ \frac{1}{2}z \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ 2x \ + \ \frac{3}{4} y \ - \ \frac{1}{2}z \ = \ 0 \ \ . $$

Using whatever algebraic method you prefer, we arrive at  $ \ x \ = \ -\frac{1}{2}y \ = \ z \ $ .  The problem isn't that the system is inconsistent -- it is *linearly dependent* , and not in a good way.  We find that $ \ x \ + \ \frac{1}{2}y \ = \ 0 \ $ , which is then the value of the argument of the logarithmic function in the first term of $ \ f(x,y,z) \ $ .  Thus, this solution plane for candidate extremal points is not in the domain of the function.

The Lagrange-multiplier method seeks locations at which level surfaces of the function to be extremized are tangent to the surface(s) described by the constraint equation(s).  This does not come with any promise that there *are* such points.  An inconsistency in the system of Lagrange equations (often) means that there are no tangent points, either because there is *no* level surface that makes contact with the constraint surface(s) at all, or that the level surfaces can only *cross* the constraint surface(s).  In this problem, the latter appears to be the case.

Here is a graph of the constraint plane, $ \ x \ + \ y \ + \ z \ = \ 1 \ $ , along with what would be the "planes of limit points" for the domain, $ \ x \ + \ \frac{1}{2}y \ = \ 0 \ $ and $ \ \frac{1}{4}y \ + \ \frac{1}{2}z \ = \ 0 \ $ .  The magneta strip marks the portion of the constraint plane which lie in the domain of $ \ f(x,y,z) \ $ .

[image]

Unfortunately, it isn't possible to show a graph of the function itself, as it has three independent variables.  The diagram below depicts three-dimensional "cross-sections" representing $ \ f(x,y,0) \ , f(x,y,1) \ , f(x,y,2) \ $ . (Negative values for $ \ z \ $ produce surfaces that don't even reach the constraint plane.)  It appears that the function "arches over" or crosses through the available portion of the constraint plane, without having tangent points.  So the function does not seem to have extrema subject to the constraint.

[image]